# Editing someone else's wrong answer to make it right

Tags: discussion, edits, wrong-answers

**I saw one user edit another's answer to turn it from blatantly incorrect to correct. This feels wrong to me. What do you think?**

The answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735623/what-are-the-and-operators-used-for/3735634#3735634). The poster referred to `|` as XOR and `^` as OR. Another user corrected this. The answer had already received 7 downvotes, so now there is a heavily downvoted correct answer.

Comment: The *Horroror!*

Comment: Considering the author of that post has since revised the post to change "Exclusive-OR" to "XOR", and did not reverse the utility of incorrect symbology, where's the foul here, exactly? It looks like it was an honest mistake, so why is fixing errors a bad thing? The existence of downvotes means that the answer has to *stay* bad?

Comment: @Grace - for the record, I posted this before the author edited his post. My point remains, though, if you imagine he hadn't. Personally, if this had been my post, I would have simply deleted it.

Comment: @Shog - the question was "what are the | and ^ operators", so mixing them up in the answer is really pretty horrible.

Comment: I've posted an answer now, so if people disagree there's no need to post your own -- just edit that one :)

Comment: @Michael - it's taking every ounce of restraint I have not to edit your post :)

Comment: And the answer is still wrong. `^` and `|` are not logical operators (unless your operands are `bool` s)

Comment: @Jon: in all seriousness, [I probably wouldn't have made that edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60758/should-i-edit-other-peoples-answers-to-remove-incorrect-content-or-should-i-ask/60763#60763). But your complaint - that a correct answer appears heavily down-voted - would still be a problem even if the author had corrected it himsefl.

Comment: @Shog - true, which is why I think the best course of action is to delete it.

Comment: @Jon: well, I'm usually in favor of users deleting their blatantly incorrect answers as well... but sadly, many do not.

Comment: @Shog9 Feature request: vote to delete answers as patently wrong

Comment: @Michael: AFAIK, we had that feature at one time, but it was removed. You can offensive-vote for deletion if it's really necessary.

Answer (score 10):

People are split on this; some people think you should modify obviously incorrect answers, some people think edits should only be for formatting and the like and shouldn't actually change the meaning of an answer.

I'm personally in the second group: if an answer is wrong than leave a comment saying so and post your own answer with the correct information; there's no need to modify someone else's wrong answer when you have the ability to post your own. I only edit an answer if it's right and I want to improve it since it's likely people searching for that problem will want to use it. I also worry about people accidentally modifying a right answer to be wrong because the editor was actually the one who was mistaken, but so far I've never seen that happen

<sub>(I somewhat discussed this [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57076/145982) as well, and agree with [George's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57076/changing-the-meaning-of-an-answer-in-an-edit/57077#57077)</sub>