# Suggested edit rejected: implementing proposed solution

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, specific-edit

[This suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2486270) has been rejected.

I haven't modified the text of the original post, but just provided the exact code corresponding to what is described. I did this after providing my own answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17587489/1951907

Since it was easy to copy-paste and modify the code I had already written, and would help the OP to compare the two proposed solutions.

Was this rejection correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the rejection seems to be correct. Generally, adding/editing code to answers provided by other users falls under 'invalid edit / radical change' categories. You gave an answer, giving credit to the other user, this is the better approach instead of putting some code which the actual user didn't add. Only the answer's owner can decide if a particular piece of code (which you suggested as edit) is appropriate or not. Whereas, suggested edits are reviewed by community at large and general guidelines are to reject such edits.

Comment: Thx for your answer. Well, according to [The FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), `When should I edit posts? Any time you feel you can make the post better, and are inclined to do so. Editing is encouraged!`. My edit indubitably makes the post better. It doesn't change at all the original meaning or intent as stated by the rewierers. At the contrary, according to the FAQ `Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged.`. The different points are just examples of usual useful edits.

Comment: After reflexion and seeing your edit: If my edit was rightfully rejected by the reason you stated, I would suggest the FAQ should be rewritten, since it definitely states a different opinion as the one in your post. (I mean the "general guidelines" of the FAQ are inconsistent qith the "general guidelines" of Meta)

Comment: (sorry for the spa ;-) ) And by the way, my `Tiny, trivial edits` have all be accepted... even when it is only removing "Thanks".

Comment: @Boris you may also view similar posts here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142161 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164102

Comment: Thx for these links. But I still have concerns: in my case, it is not about *changing* code, but *adding code*, by *implementing exactly the author answer*. None of this is related in the other posts. In addition, the solution provided is to "comment the post instead" which I definitely cannot do since it does not fit in the few hundreds character and reduced MarkDown.

Comment: Sure, but the solution is also to add your own answer (which you did). Editing is generally to improve visuals of a post and not to enhance the meat of the post. I saw your recent edits, all of them are good. You have used proper markups (like code and lists, etc.). One [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2485433) is small but I would have approved it because it removes noise from the post (not just the word "thanks" but more).

Comment: Regarding rewriting FAQ, you may post a new question tagged as [meta-tag:feature-request].

Comment: Ok, thx for your opinion/help. I'm waiting a couple of days to see if there are different opinions, then accept an answer.

Comment: Sure. You may already know this but just a friendly reminder, you may place a bounty on your question if you think that your question has not received much attention from other users.

Comment: Good point, thx. :-) I knew this but might not have think about it, since I never did it yet.

Comment: in case you may be interested, I've been thinking about not just modifying the FAQ (that I think is in the spirit of the site), but rather "fixing the issues". So I've made this [suggested feature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188499/editing-add-a-require-author-approval-checkbox)

Comment: @AzizShaikh The FAQ should not be changed in this way, because it is **intended** that editors may improve posts. The problem is not the FAQ, it's the reviewers who are not respecting the rules and going against editing which is a [core value](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) of Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

This is a borderline case. Adding sample code that implements the method described in an answer is a good thing. If you think this is how the author of the answer would write the code if he'd spend the time to get it right, then your edit is a good one.

However, such an edit is also substantial enough that you could post an answer on your own. Credit the original answerer for his method, and post your code.

Editing the existing answer is better in terms of its overall result, because it results in a single answer containing both the explanation of the method and the illustrating code. However Stack Exchange retains post ownership, and the edit is only appropriate if this is how the author would have written it. So the edit introduces a risk.

In addition, keep in mind that people who review suggested edits may not be familiar with the topic, so it is difficult for them to judge whether your code is good. While reviewers should skip a suggested edit when they cannot determine its correctness, this causes more work for reviewers. It would be better for your code to be reviewed by people who frequent the tag.

As a reviewer, I would skip this edit, and hopefully let the answerer decide. However you can't expect that of all reviewers on Stack Overflow. So making the code a separate answer may be the best course of action, all things considered, even if the end result is suboptimal.

Comment: +1, thank you again Gilles for your time in answering this one also (that I see after your other answer). Your answers are full of wise thoughts. Anyway, since the SO situation is as it is, I just decided not to edit anything except grammar/formatting, and wait to be >2k for anything more substantial. Improving an answer that may be rejected is definitely not worth my time :-)