# Is it OK to edit someone's wrong answer

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, edits, answers

This question had already took place here: [Editing someone else's wrong answer to make it right](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64841/editing-someone-elses-wrong-answer-to-make-it-right)

But there's no clear answer

My question is: Is it OK to edit someone's wrong answer to make it right and blame everyone not to post the same answer. Strange, right? It happened to me right now.

I'll add the link to the post here where you can see the first answer was wrong some user had edited the wrong answer and tells every other person in the page "not to post the same answer you could upvote the previous answer"

I don't know whether it is right or wrong.

Link to the post :  [Display another style of a portion of a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53095779/display-another-style-of-a-portion-of-a-link)

**Edit**:
I think he deleted his comments but someone has replied to his comment you can see that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53095903/10295057

**Edit 2**:
My conversation with that person: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53095918/10295057

[image]

Comment: I am confused. I do not see any edit to any answer that you mention. The only edit to your answer is yours, to fix some typo.

Comment: @ShadowWizard  see this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/53095878/10295057 the original post not the correct answer someone has edited the answer the same one is copy pasting comments on everyones' answers

Comment: What about it? It's an answer. It was not edited. There are no comments. Sometimes more than one person have the same correct answer, it's expected in trivial cases like this one, and totally legit.

Comment: You did not see it because user(how edited the worng answer) deleted his comments(about do not post duplicate answer)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Editing a post should never change its meaning or intent (see the [Edit Questions And Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) privilege page for details). So unless an edit corrects a trivial typo or introduces some other minor correction that clearly follows the author's intent, you should not edit wrong answers to make them right. Instead, you could comment explaining why the answer is wrong, or even downvote it.

Comment: Thanks, but what can we do to prevent this from not happening in future

Comment: @Prince people will make mistakes, it's part of human nature. The best we can do is help educate others. Roll back the edit and add an explanation to the edit summary explaining why this edit should never have been approved.

Comment: What if the whole answer is clearly and obviously wrong in the intended case, but works under certain (far to restrictive) premises? Like in stackoverflow.com/questions/13497203/how-to-initialize-an-array-with-only-1-values?