# Answer edits that completely change the answer?

Tags: discussion, edits

https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/98488

I was breaking in my new 10k privileges by cleaning up some pending edits and ran across this...

An anonymous editor claims to have tested this answer *extensively* and claims that the existing answer no longer works.

My knee jerk reaction is to deny it because

- The answer must have been accepted for a reason (not familiar enough with subject matter)
- Its seems it should just be submitted as an alternate answer

Obviously I'm just leaving it alone but wanted to see what the protocol on this is.

Comment: See also: [Changing the meaning of an answer in an edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57076/changing-the-meaning-of-an-answer-in-an-edit), [Should Suggested Edits change the technical content of a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78845/should-suggested-edits-change-the-technical-content-of-a-post)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The "How to edit" block that is now visible only to who doesn't have the privilege to edit all the posts reports the following points:

- fix grammatical or spelling errors
- clarify meaning **without changing it**
- correct minor mistakes
- add related resources or links
- always respect the original author

*(emphasis added)*

As the edit changes the meaning of the answer (it actually changes the answer), then the edit is not acceptable.

The user who proposed the edit should add a new answer. Changing the existing one because some conditions have been change, it's not something acceptable, IMO.

Comment: +1, too many people don't follow the second point.

Answer (score 11):

It should be rejected.

If the answer is wrong, a comment should be left. If he has his own solution, he should write his own answer.

Answer (score 2):

I agree. This should be a new answer. I'd post it as a community wiki answer and reject the edit.